# XGBOOST Java API

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, forecasting, xgboost

I'm trying to do some forecasting of sales using the XGBOOST library. But I'm using the Java API since I am more familiar with Java, than Python. Also one more thing we're trying to verify is whether there would be any performance related gains on using Python vs Java when training the model using the same dataset.

But the problem is that I have a hard time finding Python equivalent libraries for *Pandas*, *SciKit*, etc. So I used the following libraries to build DataFrames, then do some manipulation on them. Then dump it into CSV file and again use another library to read the data and perform the 80/20 split of the training and validation data sets. Once again I dump the output into a CSV file, before reading the data back into the XGBOOST library to create DMatrix.

Libraries:

- [Joinery](http://cardillo.github.io/joinery/v1.7/api/reference/joinery/DataFrame.html) for DataFrames
- Weka for splitting the data into 80/20 splits
- Official XGBOOST JVM package for modelling

I know this is not the efficient or the correct way of performing this analysis in Java. But at the same time, I do not see any examples where all this is done using Java or any libraries in Java.

I wanted to check if any of you have performed XGBOOST analysis of your data using the Java implementation of the library. Also, if you have used any packages to create DataFrames, perform manipulations, etc before splitting the data into train and test datasets.

Any help would he highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use ND4J (https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j) for for ndarray manipulations and convert a flat matrix for XGBoost to use via DMatrix.

Although I am mostly using ndarray related operations instead of DataFrames, I believe it's feasible to implement them in JVM languages without too much trouble.